# Download function with DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

Does DocuSign have an API that allows an app integration (in my case via SharePoint or Teams) to download a signed document from the DocuSign repository?  At this point, I can only see a manual process whereby a person has to access DocuSign and click on the download button.

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-downloading-documents

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.
One approach is to use the [DocuSign for SharePoint integration](https://www.docusign.com/solutions/microsoft/sharepoint-online).

The other is to use the [Agreement Actions](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-agreement-actions) feature.
In both cases you can get documents automatically downloaded into SharePoint.